# Make a video play when i click on an image inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I take a video photo from youtube by iframe.
You can see it when you click on HTML button so the photo is load up but I also try to make the photo to change to a video in the iframe after I click on the picture. Thanks to all..!

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
</head>
<body>
   <header></header>
     <nav>
        <a target="page" id="img" onclick="html()" href="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/bWPMSSsVdPk/hqdefault.jpg">
           <button>HTML</button>
        </a>
     </nav>
     <iframe name="page" src="" frameborder="1"></iframe>
     <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

This is The JAVASCRIPT:

```
function html(){    
    var iframes = document.getElementById('iframes');
    iframes.innerHTML ='https://www.youtube.com/embed/bWPMSSsVdPk';     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something like what you are looking for?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
      <style>
        .hidden {
          display: None;
        }

        .shown {
          display: "";
        }
      </style>
      <script>
         function html(img) {
          var iframe = document.getElementById("frame");

          img.setAttribute("class", "hidden");
          iframe.setAttribute("class", "shown");
        }
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <header></header>
      <nav>
        <button>HTML</button>
      </nav>
      <img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/bWPMSSsVdPk/hqdefault.jpg" frameborder="1" class="shown" id="image" onClick="html(this);"/>
      <iframe id="frame" name="page" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bWPMSSsVdPk" frameborder="1" class="hidden"></iframe>
      <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

You might want to fiddle with the height and width attributes of your elements, but this is how I would achieve the result you're looking for.

Comment: someting close , just when i click on the photo its will show the vedio , not when i click on the button :) is it possible ?